# How to output strings in a two lists to display sideway in python

Tags: python, string, list

I need a code to make my two separate lists display sideway like this,

```
x = ["toyota", "lexus"]
y = ["camry", "quest"]
```

I want some kinda of output like

```
x                   y
Toyota           Camry
lexus            quest
```

I hope you all even get what i mean.

Don't even know how to code it.

Comment: yes i do know how to do that, but i don't think that makes it display by it side. You know like they display casts at the end of a movie?

Comment: oh i get you now ok

Comment: Well this website is where you show your failed attempts so we can see where you went wrong and help you from there.

Comment: @quamrana no it's a site where people ask on-topic answerable questions, code is not mandatory.

Comment: Well, it can be whatever you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[zip()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_zip.asp) is a good place to start.  Then just find some way to present it how you want

```
makes = ["toyota", "lexus"]
models = ["camry", "quest"]

print('Make','Model',sep="\t")
cars = zip(makes ,models) # list(cars) = [('toyota', 'camry'), ('lexus', 'quest')]

for car in cars :
    print('\t'.join(car))
```

gives

> ```
> Make      Model
> toyota    camry
> lexus     quest
> ```

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
x = ["toyota", "lexus"]
y = ["camry", "quest"]

for cars in zip(x, y):
    print(cars[0] + " " + cars[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

1. It is a string formatting problem.
2. ```
   x = ["toyota", "lexus"]
   y = ["camry", "quest"]

   print(" x              |           y")
   for i in range(len(x)):
         len_x = len(x[i])
         print(x[i],end = "");
         for j in range(16 - len_x):
             print(" ",end = "")
             print("|",end = "")
         for j in range(10):
             print(" ",end = "")
             print(y[i])

   output:
    x              |           y
   toyota          |          camry
   lexus           |          quest
   ```